# DropDownList always giving me the 0th element

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm writing a small addition to a web app and I'm using a DropDownList which I need to access which element is currently chosen. I've done it before, in this project I do it quite a bit, but for some reason, this last DropDownList always returns the 0th element.

Here's the XAML for the DDL:

```
<td><asp:DropDownList Width="230" ID="d_serviceList" runat="server" Autopostback = "false"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

And here's the method that I am calling:

```
    protected void deleteService_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceDal.DeleteService(d_serviceList.SelectedItem.Text, d_categoryList.SelectedItem.Text, d_practiceList.SelectedItem.Text);
        required.Checked = false;
        message2.Visible = true;
        message.Visible = false;
    }
```

where ServiceDal.DeleteService(string, string string) takes the strings and runs a backend query. The queries are working fine, but the first of three DDL (the d_serviceList) returns the 0th element EVERY time, while all the other ones do not.

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you post the markup of the others drops?

Comment: Check your postback. Make sure when you click the button, the dropDownList is not re-binding and setting the selected to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into selected index changed action in the drop down box this should allow you to specify either what the 0th element is or which element you want to have saved.

```
Protected void d_serviceList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TempString = d_serviceList.SelectedItem.ToSting();
}
```

Would allow you to have exactly what is selected no matter what happens unless you manually change the index.